On the existence of a maximal level set for an $L^\infty$ function
Suppose to have a function $\rho \in L^\infty(\Omega)$, where $\Omega$ is an open and bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$. One can define the level set $\{\rho = c\}$, at least up to set of zero measure. Does it exists a specific representant $\tilde \rho$, in the class of equivalence of $\rho$, such that for any other representant $\rho$ we have $\{\rho = c\} \subset \{\tilde \rho = c \}$?
One obvious way to tackle the problem is to use Zorn's Lemma. However, the union of a non-countable ascending chain of measurable sets needs not to be measurable and I don't see a way to bypass this issue.

You came really close to answering your own question. The inability to use Zorn's lemma basically gives you a counterexample, assuming $\rho$ is not a constant almost everywhere. Namely, if $\tilde \rho$ were a function that isn't constant almost everywhere, then the set $\{\tilde\rho \neq c\}$ is nonempty, thus containing some point $x$. The new function $\hat\rho$ that has the same values as $\tilde \rho$ on $\Omega \backslash \{x\}$ and $\hat\rho(x)=c$ contradicts the defining property of $\tilde \rho$.
